# Sublime Text 3 php-fmt won't work

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I'm trying to use php-fmt plugin for ST3, I installed it, but when i use the keys it doesn't do anything.
I think I setup everything correctly but the php file doesn't get any format.
I can use PHP on command line... I followed the setup.
I'm on OSX, using MAMP php 5.5.10

also if i use the command 'analyze'
i get the message

```
Autocomplete and autoimport need building a database of terms.
Please, fill in below with the proper location for this database.
Keep in mind that the best location is always the root of the project, therefore limiting the size and ensuring speed.
```

If you have any idea why it doesn't work please help or suggest an alternative to format PHP code
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the the menu go to Preferences > Package Settings > phpfmt > Settings - User

Edit the file that will open in result of the previous action.

Specify the "php_bin" according to your php binary location,

It should contain something like this:

```
{
    "enable_auto_align": false,
    "indent_with_space": true,
    "passes":
    [
    ],
    "php_bin": "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php",
    "psr1": true,
    "psr2": true,
    "version": 2
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for newer version.

**SublimeText 3 and PHPfmt 4**

On the the menu go to Preferences > Package Settings > phpfmt > Settings - User
and add below code, please make sure PHP >= 5.6 is installed on path C:/php/php.exe or you can replace with your PHP.exe path below:

```
{
 "version": 4,
 "php_bin":"C:/php/php.exe",
 "format_on_save":true,
}
```